# Autocompleting Parameters of a function in intelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, autocomplete

I have a function with parameters.
I like to use this function and would like to see the parameters that I have to provide to this function.

How can I force IntelliJ, that it shows me the parameters needed for that function when my cursor is in the () of that function ? Ctrl-Space do not help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try CTRL+P
its shows you the type and the name

Press CTRL+SHIFT+A and search for Parameter Info and it will show u your hotkey

Comment: Perfect Thanks a lot.